# Trouble during generate XLS programmatically

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat6, business-objects

This code i have deployed on server side to convert a rep file (BO File )to xls file using macro of XLs.I invoked the macro through this jsp call and Macro convert .rep file to xls file . . When invoke the jsp from client side  on server system donot open xls sheet , but when i try to run same code as a standalone java code it work. Here i hjave attached a sample code.Could please help me.

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %><%@ page contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel"%> <html><head></head> <body> <% String cmdLine = "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Office12/EXCEL.EXE\" /e/\"D:\\North%20America\\Workspace%20Defined_2013-03-23-06-50-50.rep\" D:\\NewFolder\\Converter.xlsm"; try{Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdLine); } catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); } %> </body> </html>
```

Comment: Please add a detailed error message.

Comment: Are you well aware that Java/JSP code runs in webserver and not in webbrowser? You seem to expect somehow that Java/JSP code is executed in physically the same machine as where the webbrowser runs. This is completely untrue. JSP is a HTML code generator. Rightclick page in browser, do *View Source* to see what exactly the JSP has produced and the browser has retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

you cant do it like that. If you need to open excel when you call a jsp you need to set the content type of response. ie. application/vnd.ms-excel

```
<%@ page contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel" %>
```

This will indicate the browser incoming data stream is ms excel and browser will handle it accordingly

Comment: This open up a XLs file in clinet side . I want to save the xls file with some name into server folder.

Comment: This code i have deployed on server side to convert a rep file (BO File )to xls file using macro of XLs.I invoked the macro through this jsp call and Macro convert .rep file to xls file . <%@ page import="java.io.*" %><%@ page contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel"%>
<html><head></head>
<body>
<%
String cmdLine = "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Office12/EXCEL.EXE\" /e/\"D:\\North%20America\\Workspace%20Defined_2013-03-23-06-50-50.rep\" D:\\NewFolder\\Converter.xlsm";
try{Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdLine);
}
catch(Exception e){
 e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
</body>
</html>

Comment: What you are trying to do is fundamentally incorrect and impossible. Jsp gets executed in server, however you are trying  to access files which resides in client(while jsp gets executed). You need to move all those files into serverside and produce a excel file and send that over the wire to client, and also I think your choice of technology is incorrect as well. Do you really want 2tier architecture for this? If you do is JSP right choice ?